# Twig: if is_granted('ROLE_MANAGER') check is not granted

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to check if a role is not granted. I have to display something only for USER but MANAGER is the hierarchy above.

To get that I am doing:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_MANAGER') %}
{% else %}
      my message 
{% endif %}
```

Which is not really nice. What can be the correct syntax for:

```
{% if is_NOT_granted('ROLE_MANAGER') %}
```

ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can simply check as follow:

```
 {% if is_granted('ROLE_MANAGER') == false %}
                  my message 
 {% endif %}
```

Hope this help

Comment: `if not is_granted('ROLE_MANAGER')`

Answer (score 74):

Or again

```
{% if not is_granted('ROLE_MANAGER') %}

   my message 
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
{{ is_granted('ROLE_MANAGER') ? 'true message' : 'false message' }}
```

or to leave the true output empty:

```
{{ is_granted('ROLE_MANAGER') == false ? 'false message' }}
```